# Next value per group in SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to fix a data quality issue and I have the following table `origin`:

```
WITH origin AS (
  SELECT 1 AS item_id, 'cake' as item_group, DATE '2020-04-01' AS start_date, DATE '2020-12-07' AS end_date, 1 as group_rank  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'cake', DATE '2020-12-07',DATE '2020-12-31', 2 as group_rank  UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'cake', DATE '2020-12-07',DATE '2020-12-31', 2 as group_rank UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 'cake', DATE '2020-12-07',DATE '2020-12-31', 2 as group_rank UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 'cake', DATE '2020-12-07',DATE '2020-12-31', 2 as group_rank UNION ALL
  SELECT 6, 'cake', DATE '2020-12-31',DATE '2021-12-07', 3 as group_rank UNION ALL
  SELECT 7, 'cake', DATE '2020-12-31',DATE '2021-12-07', 3 as group_rank UNION ALL

  SELECT 8, 'pie', DATE '2020-12-07',DATE '2020-12-31', 1 as group_rank UNION ALL
  SELECT 9, 'pie', DATE '2020-12-31',DATE '2021-12-07', 2 as group_rank UNION ALL
  SELECT 10, 'pie', DATE '2020-12-31',DATE '2021-12-07', 2 as group_rank 
)
select *
from origin
```

| item_id | item_group | start_date | end_date | group_rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | cake | 2020-04-01 | 2020-12-07 | 1 |
| 2 | cake | 2020-12-07 | 2020-12-31 | 2 |
| 3 | cake | 2020-12-07 | 2020-12-31 | 2 |
| 4 | cake | 2020-12-07 | 2020-12-31 | 2 |
| 5 | cake | 2020-12-07 | 2020-12-31 | 2 |
| 6 | cake | 2020-12-31 | 2021-12-07 | 3 |
| 7 | cake | 2020-12-31 | 2021-12-07 | 3 |
| 8 | pie | 2020-12-07 | 2020-12-31 | 1 |
| 9 | pie | 2020-12-31 | 2021-12-07 | 2 |
| 10 | pie | 2020-12-31 | 2021-12-07 | 2 |

Every row is a unique item, which is of a certain item_group: `pie` or `cake`. Items within the group are ranked according to the `start_date`. The problem with the table is that when I do a join with a calendar table, because some items have overlapping start_date and end_date (1 item ends the same day when the other one end ) I end up having duplicates. What I want to achieve, I want to fix the `end_dates` (-1 day)  of the old items.

For that I need to understand whether the items are overlapping within 1 day. I thought i'd use the rank to find the next value *within the group*: basically check current rank, find the one higher, take the start_date of the higher rank. But i couldn't figure out the way to get this right.

So my ideal table is the following:

```
WITH final_result AS (
  SELECT 1 AS item_id, 'cake' as item_group, DATE '2020-04-01' AS start_date, DATE '2020-12-07' AS end_date, 1 as group_rank, DATE '2020-12-07' as next_group_start_date, 1 as  end_date_equals_next_group_start_date, DATE '2020-12-06' as new_end_date UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'cake', DATE '2020-12-07',DATE '2020-12-31', 2 as group_rank, DATE '2020-12-31', 1, DATE '2020-12-30' UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'cake', DATE '2020-12-07',DATE '2020-12-31', 2 as group_rank, DATE '2020-12-31', 1, DATE '2020-12-30' UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 'cake', DATE '2020-12-07',DATE '2020-12-31', 2 as group_rank, DATE '2020-12-31', 1, DATE '2020-12-30' UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 'cake', DATE '2020-12-07',DATE '2020-12-31', 2 as group_rank, DATE '2020-12-31', 1, DATE '2020-12-30' UNION ALL
  SELECT 6, 'cake', DATE '2020-12-31',DATE '2021-12-07', 3 as group_rank, NULL, 0, DATE '2020-12-07' UNION ALL
  SELECT 7, 'cake', DATE '2020-12-31',DATE '2021-12-07', 3 as group_rank, NULL, 0, DATE '2020-12-07' UNION ALL

  SELECT 8, 'pie', DATE '2020-12-07',DATE '2020-12-31', 1 as group_rank, DATE '2020-12-31', 1, DATE '2020-12-30' UNION ALL
  SELECT 9, 'pie', DATE '2020-12-31',DATE '2021-12-07', 2 as group_rank, NULL, 0, DATE '2020-12-06' UNION ALL
  SELECT 10, 'pie', DATE '2020-12-31',DATE '2021-12-07', 2 as group_rank, NULL, 0, DATE '2020-12-06'
)
select *
from final_result
```

| item_id | item_group | start_date | end_date | group_rank | next_group_start_date | end_date_equals_next_group_start_date | new_end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | cake | 2020-04-01 | 2020-12-07 | 1 | 2020-12-07 | 1 | 2020-12-06 |
| 2 | cake | 2020-12-07 | 2020-12-31 | 2 | 2020-12-31 | 1 | 2020-12-30 |
| 3 | cake | 2020-12-07 | 2020-12-31 | 2 | 2020-12-31 | 1 | 2020-12-30 |
| 4 | cake | 2020-12-07 | 2020-12-31 | 2 | 2020-12-31 | 1 | 2020-12-30 |
| 5 | cake | 2020-12-07 | 2020-12-31 | 2 | 2020-12-31 | 1 | 2020-12-30 |
| 6 | cake | 2020-12-31 | 2021-12-07 | 3 | NULL | 0 | 2020-12-07 |
| 7 | cake | 2020-12-31 | 2021-12-07 | 3 | NULL | 0 | 2020-12-07 |
| 8 | pie | 2020-12-07 | 2020-12-31 | 1 | 2020-12-31 | 1 | 2020-12-30 |
| 9 | pie | 2020-12-31 | 2021-12-07 | 2 | NULL | 0 | 2020-12-06 |
| 10 | pie | 2020-12-31 | 2021-12-07 | 2 | NULL | 0 | 2020-12-06 |

By identifying the `new_group_start_date` I can understand whether there is an overlap on a day. `end_date_equals_next_group_start_date`shows whether `start_date` = `new_group_start_date`, i.e. there is an overlap. If so - I can create a `new_end_date`, which is `end_date` - 1.

Comment: you have to show us expected results  very hard to understand what you want.

Comment: I added markdown table. Hopefully it clarifies things

Comment: @hamsy https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: @hamsy . . . Your problem may be unsolvable.  Why don't you want to combine rows when they have the same data?

Comment: If `new_end_date` is also an `end_date` from another record, do you require to decrement it at new ? (I mean `new_end_date = end_date - n` with n>1)

Comment: @gordonLinoff I wish I could do that. But those are unique items ( as they have unique id ) and need to be counted for business logic

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is use the `LEAD()` window function.

```
SELECT 
    *, 
    LEAD(start_date, 1) OVER(PARTITION BY item_group ORDER BY group_rank) AS next_group_start_date
FROM origin
```

This works but doesn't give the exact result you were expecting. In order to get the expected result you need to join the `origin` table with a table using the `LEAD()` window function a distinct `item_group, group, start_date` table.

```
SELECT
    *,
    end_date - end_date_equals_next_group_start_date AS new_end_date
FROM (
    SELECT 
        origin.*, 
        b.next_group_start_date,
        CASE 
            WHEN origin.end_date = b.next_group_start_date
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END AS end_date_equals_next_group_start_date
    FROM origin
    JOIN (
        SELECT
            item_group,
            group_rank,
            LEAD(start_date, 1) OVER(PARTITION BY item_group ORDER BY group_rank) AS next_group_start_date
        FROM (
            SELECT DISTINCT item_group, group_rank, start_date
            FROM origin
        ) a
    ) b ON origin.item_group = b.item_group and origin.group_rank = b.group_rank
) c
```

Here's a [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=b7354843249f07789a776bb1fc1dcb87) of the query

Comment: Edited to match with your question update.